# How to make haproxy use a list of proxy?

Tags: proxy, haproxy

squid can use a proxy list like:

```
cache_peer %(host)s parent %(port)s 0 no-query weighted-round-robin weight=%(weight)s connect-fail-limit=2 allow-miss max-conn=5
```

then just access squid port, it would auto choose a proxy to access internet for me.

How do I achieve this in haproxy?

Comment: HAProxy is a reverse-proxy only.  You don't use it to access the Internet.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I want to deploy a proxy service which use a proxy pool, `squid` can do this by turning each proxy in a proxy list to the format I mentioned in question,  then add the formated proxy list to squid.conf would work.